# Drop a file in the root directory with bash?

Tags: bash

I have around 30 servers that have a single server's SSH keys in authorized_keys.

I want to write a program which connects one by one to these boxes and does two things.

[1] srm's various directories with the -R flag
[2] leaves a txt document in the root directory

I know this would be possible through bash but I don't have the experience to write something like this.

Can anyone help me out? The servers run on the sshd port.

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop + `ssh user@host -p port command` can get it done

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read server; do
  #execute commands on remote server
  ssh user@$server ifconfig
  #copy local file over
  scp /path/to/file user@$server:/path/on/remote_server/
done < servers.txt
```